# Onload method when the page is loading VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to call the method when the page is loading. So far I call the method when I click, but when I try to use mounted to automatically call the method, it keeps failing, do you have some suggestion?

Below is the code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <AppHeader></AppHeader>
    <div style="display: flex">
      <ul>
        <li
          style="cursor: pointer"
          v-for="exchange of profileExchanges"
          :key="exchange.id"
          @click="getImagesByExchange(exchange.id)"
        >
          <div style="padding: 20px; border: solid 2px red">
            <h3>Brand: {{exchange.brand}}</h3>
            <p>Description: {{exchange.description}}</p>
            <p>Category: {{exchange.category}}</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div>
        <span style="margin: 10px" v-for="url of exchangeImageUrls" :key="url">
          <img width="250px" :src="url" />
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import AppHeader from '@/components/Header5'
export default {
  components: {
    AppHeader
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('exchange/getExchangesByProfile', this.$store.state.auth.user.profile.user)
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedExchangeId: '',
      exchanges: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    user() {
      return this.$store.state.auth.user
    },
    profile() {
      return this.user.profile || {}
    },
    profileExchanges() {
      return this.$store.getters['exchange/profileExchanges']
    },
    exchangeImageUrls() {
      return this.$store.getters['exchange/imageUrls']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getImagesByExchange(exchangeId) {
      this.$store.dispatch('exchange/getImagesByExchange', exchangeId)
    },
    getListings() {

    },
    updateProfile(profile, closeModal) {
      this.$store.dispatch('auth/updateProfile', profile)
        .then(_ => {
          closeModal()
        })
    }
  }   
}

</script>
```

I try to put mounted like this

```
mounted: function() {
    this.getImagesByExchange() // Calls the method before page loads
},
```

But it keeps failing. I guess the problem is how to access the key, but not sure.

Comment: `this.getImagesByExchange()` expects an argument of `exchangeId`.

Comment: You need to make sure to call `getExchangesByProfile` before calling `getImagesByExchange` and getting the `exchangeId`

Comment: hi, thank you for the reply, can you give the example or code of it? 

Do you mean this 

mounted: function() {
    this.getExchangesByProfile()
    this.getImagesByExchange(exchange.id) // Calls the method before page loads
  },

Comment: I try to use this 

this.$vnode.key as parameter , but still not works

Comment: Hi Tony, i insert exchangeId but its not defined 

this.getImagesByExchange(exchangeId)

Comment: Please update with the actual error. *"It keeps failing"* is not enough error definition. Ideally you should provide a [mcve] (use `codesanbox.io` if you need a multi-file node based snippet editor). From what you've shown so far, `getImagesByExchange`  is different than `getExchangesByProfile`. Do you have a `getExchangesByProfile` action in `exchanges` store module?

Comment: Hi Tao, many thanks for the response... 

Yes, i get it from the store module. I will try to create the MRE in the codesandbox.io soon so it gives better information of the situation...

thank you really apreciate it

Answer (score 1):

If the `selectedExchangeId` is already not set, you could get the first element of the `profileExchanges` array and pass the `id` to the `getImagesByExchange` function:

```
mounted() {
    this.getImagesByExchange(this.profileExchanges[0].id) // Calls the method before page loads
},
```

**EDIT**

Looking again at your code one could suppose that, at the moment the component is `mounted` the `profileExchanges` property *might* not yet be set. One way to handle this is to call both of them inside the `created` like this:

```
async created() {
    await this.$store.dispatch(
       'exchange/getExchangesByProfile',
        this.$store.state.auth.user.profile.user
    );
    
    if (this.profileExchanges && this.profileExchanges.length) {
        this.getImagesByExchange(this.profileExchanges[0].id);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Hatef, thank you for the information 

hmmm I try yoir suggestion and it still can not call the getImagesByExchange so far

mounted() {
      this.getImagesByExchange(this.profileExchanges[0].id) // Calls the method before page loads
    },  

but thank you for the response.

Comment: Hmm, could you update your question with the last version of your component?

Comment: @alfazaid please have a look at the edit. Hope it helps :)